# What damage does the manyfang dagger multiply?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, weapons, damage

The ***manyfang dagger*** (*Serpent Kingdoms* 152) (32,302 gp; 1 lb.), in part, says, "A manyfang dagger thus deals quadruple damage on each successful hit, or quintuple damage on a critical hit."

What damage is multiplied by this weapon? That is, is this just a fancy way of saying the weapon deals 4d4 points of damage or 5d4 points of damage on a critical hit? Or does the weapon multiply by 4 or 5 *everything* that would be normally affected by a multiplier, such as a critical or or a valorous weapon (like extra damage from Strength, the special ability favored enemy, the special ability insightful strike, yet not sneak attack damage)?

I found conversations on the Internet that assume it works one way or the other but no debate. I could find no official word on how the weapon works.

The first option makes the weapon seem overpriced, but the second option makes the weapon seem overpowered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Multiplying damage is a known, defined thing](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/combatStatistics.htm#multiplyingDamage) in 3.5e:

> #### Multiplying Damage
>
> Sometimes you multiply damage by some factor, such as on a critical hit. Roll the damage (with all modifiers) multiple times and total the results. Note: When you multiply damage more than once, each multiplier works off the original, unmultiplied damage.
>
> *Exception:* Extra damage dice over and above a weapon’s normal damage are never multiplied.

There are a number of examples of multiplying damage, including the core examples of [critical hits](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#criticalHits) (which repeats the above rules, and then refers to it as being “doubled” or otherwise “multiplied”) and [lances in a mounted charge](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#lance) (“A lance deals double damage when used from the back of a charging mount”). There are also numerous non-core examples like the *ruby* and *diamond nightmare blade* Diamond Mind maneuvers from *Tome of Battle*, the decisive strike alternate monk class feature *Player’s Handbook II*, and... the *manyfang dagger*.

For extra confirmation, we have the \$\times5\$ multiplier on a critical hit: that is consistent with a weapon that has a \$20\$/\$\times2\$ critical property, but comes with a \$\times4\$ multiplier default: then, when you roll a critical hit, you perform the usual odd multiplier addition:

\begin{align}
\times4 \times2 &= \\
\times1 + (\times4-1) + (\times2-1) &= \\
\times(1 + 3 + 1) &= \times5
\end{align}

If the *manyfang dagger* referred only to the base damage die when it was talking about quadrupling, it would be very weird to then refer to the entire damage expression when quintupling. If it referred only to the base damage die, I would instead expect the 4d4 to be doubled, not everything to be quintupled.

And, of course, if they just meant 4d4, why go through this whole rigmarole instead of just *saying* it has a 4d4 base damage die?

So no, “quadruple damage” is not a fancy way of saying 4d4. It is saying that you “Roll the damage (with all modifiers [excepting extra damage dice over and above a weapon’s normal damage]) multiple times and total the results,” and that makes the *manyfang dagger* preposterous. So you should probably just ban it, and should give *Serpent Kingdoms* in general a pretty critical glare. Certainly don’t let anyone *shapechange* into a sarrukh, is what I’m saying. (But seriously, don’t stop there; *ability rip* and *venomfire* also spring to mind immediately as theoretical optimization stars. There very well may be more.)

Comment: Okay, I'm almost on board *except* for that pesky *quintuple damage on a critical hit* part. Because that kind of multiplier makes it sound like the *dagger* means the 4d4 points of damage plus modifiers yet on a critical hit instead 5d4 points of damage plus modifiers *twice.* Can this answer address that implication specifically?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I am confused why that is a sticking point—I almost wrote it up as a strong confirmation that what we have here is a basic ×4 multiplier, and a 20/×2 critical property, so that on a critical hit you get your typical \$\times1+(\times4-1)+(\times2-1)=\times(1+3+1)=\times5\$ due to the game’s particular multiplier stacking rules.

Comment: It's a sticking point (hah!)  because the longer description of the *dagger* says that "when it hits, three phantom blades briefly whirl into existence around the main blade, stabbing and slicing the same target," yet the damage from those phantom blades doesn't also seem to be multiplied on a critical hit and *that* brings into question whether *any* of the wielder's flat bonuses should also apply to the phantom blades.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I took the quadrupled damage to be the mechanical representation of those blades—precisely mirroring what the real one is doing—but only the real one can score a critical hit (so it still gets doubled, while the other three simply deal their regular damage, for \$\times5\$ total). If they meant for the extra blades to just add on another 1d4 damage each, it could just *say that*.

Comment: And phrase something clearly and concisely so as not to invite controversy? Are we playing the same game here? `:-)` Indeed, I'm *also* imagining a similar possibility—that only the real blade can score a critical hit—, but I'm also imagining a DM ruling that, for example, the phantom blades don't benefit from the wielder's special abilities because the wielder is *not* wielding the phantom blades *because* only the real blade can score critical hits.

Comment: (I'm just putting forth alternatives, by the way. This isn't even my hill to die on—the *dagger* is one of the handful of things I just ban in my campaigns because it's dumb *either way.*)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Oh, I know, I have minimal expectations of them in terms how things are worded. But this particular thing, we have many, many examples of them wording *this* clearly and concisely. Why would *this particular one* have failed so hard on the wording—unless they actually meant something else? And, for that matter, the wording here really is just the same as found on, say, the lance (barring the mounted charge condition).

Comment: That's fair. I guess I really shouldn't've expected *Serpent Kingdoms* — of all books — to err on the side of *reduced* power. It may, however, be worthwhile to address the asker's assumption that for some reason precision damage isn't likewise dealt four times (keeping in mind — or not! — the *Rules Compendium*'s stealth errata on precision damage volleys.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Precision damage is always[?] represented as extra damage dice, so no, they would not be multiplied.

Comment: So the *manyfang dagger* creates 3 extra daggers and each of those extra daggers deals the wielder's extra Strength damage and favored enemy damage and everything else, but because the text says it *deals quadruple damage on each successful hit*, it's not *really* like getting hit by 1 dagger four times (five on a critical hit) but… *Darn it! Curse you,* Serpent Kingdoms! *I spit on your grave!*

Comment: @Kryan Precision damage that is not damage dice: swashbuckler 3 and maybe the Craven feat