# Are there any feats that grant at-will ranged attacks that scale off of character level?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, character-levels

Feats which grant damaging effects that scale based on character level seem to be uncommon, but they definitely exist--for example, for monk-type (Superior Unarmed Strike) and rogue-type (Craven) builds. I can't find any designed for blaster mage-type builds, however.

Reserve feats effectively scale based on caster level, since their damage is based on your highest available spell level, which isn't really the same as scaling based on character level. The Shape Soulmeld feat can get you Dissolving Spittle, which you can kinda force to scale off of character level, but only by buying more essentia feats. That's closer to what I want, but it's pretty feat-expensive.

So... Is there any other feat that can give heavily-multiclassed character some sort of pseudo-eldritch-blast that actually remains (at least somewhat) useful at higher levels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No feats *really* meet this need, and those that may come close aren't very attractive

A feat that grants a creature that can't cast spells a warlock-style ersatz *eldritch blast* that scales with the creature's Hit Dice isn't, so far as I can tell, a thing. I mean, below *are* a few feats that may be interesting, but they're pretty much it. They're also kind of bad, possess intense prerequisites, or both.

### Feats that grant a mundane creature a ranged attack that scales with level but has limited uses per day

*The question asks for unlimited-use abilities, and these aren't those, but there are so few options available that including these seemed natural, for comparison if nothing else. Skip to the next section if these aren't of interest.*

- The general feat ***Ki* Barrage** (*Dragon* #306 54–5) has absurd prerequisites: a Dexterity score of 16 (yes, that's both accurate and nonstandard), a Wisdom score of 19, and the feats [Improved Unarmed Strike](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#improved-unarmed-strike) (*Player's Handbook* 96), [Precise Shot](http://dndsrd.net/actionsInCombat.html#precise-shot) (98), [Point Blank Shot](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#point-blank-shot) (*ibid.*), and [Stunning Fist](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#stunning-fist) (101) and this last feat itself also has a prerequisite of a base attack bonus of +8 if not acquired as, for instance, a monk bonus feat. Anyway, the feat allows the creature to make normal ranged attacks (i.e. it can make its iterative attacks when it takes the full attack action) that possess a 30 ft. range increment and deal the creature's unarmed strike damage except the damage is force damage; each attack expends a use of the Stunning Fist feat. Even a nonmonk's unarmed strike damage can scale with character level—albeit not very well—*via* the feat **Superior Unarmed Strike** (*Tome of Battle* 33). Don't marry the feat based on my description here: A raft of other restrictions apply; read the feat yourself first. It's terrible.
- [This fine answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/170482/8610) already mentions the domain feat **Magic Devotion** (*Complete Champion* 61) that has no prerequisites and allows the creature 1/day to take a standard action to use a supernatural ability to make a ranged touch attack against a target within 30 ft. +5 ft./character level that, if successful, deals 1d6 points of damage per 2 character levels. The feat can be used again by expending 2 turn undead attempts or by taking the feat multiple times. As a DM, I've found the feat Magic Devotion occasionally attractive for monsters that otherwise lack a ranged attack (e.g. a mildly optimized advanced (7 HD) [wight](http://dndsrd.net/monstersTtoZ.html#wight) Clr 1 can typically employ the feat Magic Devotion 4/day and is about CR 4 if the *Monster Manual* is to be believed and if that matters).
- The general feat that's also a fighter bonus feat **Ring the Golden Bell** (*Dragon Compendium Volume 1* 105) possesses prerequisites that are still absurd, but not quite as absurd as the *Ki* Barrage feat: A Wisdom score of 13, a base attack bonus of +5, and the feats Improved Unarmed Strike, Stunning Fist, and [Weapon Focus](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#weapon-focus) (unarmed strike) (*PH* 102). This investment gives the creature the ability to make an unarmed strike as a ranged attack with a range of up to 5 ft. +5 ft. × the creature's Wisdom bonus. The creature can make such an attack but 1/day + a number of times per day equal to the creature's Wisdom bonus. Again, the feat Superior Unarmed Strike sees a creature's unarmed strike damage scale with character level.

### Feats that grant a mundane creature a ranged attack that scales with level and has no use limit

*These are actually what the question asks for. Okay, not really. They approach what the question asks for.*

- The martial arts style **Northern Fist Mastery** (*Dragon* #315 66) isn't a feat but I think it's close enough because it's gained automatically by a creature that possesses *all* of the following feats: [Combat Expertise](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#combat-expertise) (*PH* 92), Falling Star Strike (*Dragon* #303 60), Freezing the Lifeblood (*Complete Warrior* 99), Improved Unarmed Strike, Pain Touch (*CW* 103), Stunning Fist, and Unbalancing Strike (*Oriental Adventures* 66). (So you know, those feats, in turn, mandate a Wisdom score of 17 and a base attack bonus of +10.) In other words, there's no reason for a creature to take all those feats except to get this style, and for all those feats the creature gains the ability to take a full-round action to make one ranged attack against a target that's within 5 ft. per 5 character levels. (That's not a typo—its maximum range is 10 ft. at levels 10–14, for example.) If successful, the attack deals the creature's unarmed strike damage. Once more, the feat Superior Unarmed Strike sees a creature's unarmed strike damage scale with character level. Really, just don't do this.
- The monstrous feat **Spit Venom** (*Serpent Kingdoms* 147) has as a prerequisite a poison bite attack. The feat allows a creature to make a ranged touch attack at a target within 30 ft. that, if successful, delivers the target's poison as if it were a contact poison. In the same book is the yuan-ti graft ***poison fangs*** (154) (8,000 gp; graft) that grants a poison bite that, if successful, deals 1d6 points of Constitution ability damage as its primary damage and secondary damage. The saving throw DC against this poison scales with character level (DC = 10 + ½ the creature's Hit Dice + the creature's Constitution modifier). (Other methods of gaining a poisonous bite are beyond this question's scope, but if this option's entertained, [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/134651/8610) may also be of interest.) While *Serpent Kingdoms* is chock-a-block with broken material (e.g. the *manyfang dagger* (152 and [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/120857/8610)), the sarrukh (80–1 and [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/150063/8610) and [everywhere](http://pun-pun)), *venomfire* (158 and [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/137399/8610))), this reader doesn't consider among that broken material the feat Spit Venom (see below).
- The general feat **Thunderclap** (*Savage Species* 40) has as its prerequisite the feats [Improved Unarmed Strike](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#improved-unarmed-strike) (*Player's Handbook* 96) and [Power Attack](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#power-attack) (98) and a Strength score of 30. Yes, 30. Such a creature can at will take a standard action to create a 5-ft.-per-Hit-Die [cone](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#cone-cylinder-line-or-sphere) (read that again) that requires those caught within to make a Fortitude saving throw (DC = 10 + ½ the creature's Hit Dice + the creature's Constitution modifier). Success means the victim is unaffected. Failure means that for the encounter the victim is [deafened](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#deafened) (and 20% spell failure is a debuff not to be scoffed at). Failure by 5 or more also means that the victim is rendered [prone](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#prone) (also no scoffing—see [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/100768/8610)). Again, my strong high-HD monsters have used this feat to good effect, but it also works for [Hulk](https://xombiedirge.com/post/3663116236/venom-vs-hulk-hand-clap-and-your-done-sorry)-[level](https://www.incrediblehulkonline.com/torchthunderclap.html)-[strength](https://www.reddit.com/r/MarvelAvengersProject/comments/bztpao/the_fact_that_this_move_is_in_the_game_has_got_me/) PCs. (To be clear, though, this effect deals no actual damage.)

(This list excludes feats like Earthquake Stomp (*Secrets of Xen'drik* 134), Mighty Roar (*Savage Species* 37), and Shockwave (*Draconomicon* 73) that have effects that aren't really *per se* ranged. (The feat Thunderclap is included even though it's a cone because the cone is usually *so big* that it might as well be ranged.) Also excluded are feats like Fling Ally (*Races of Stone* 139–40) *et al.* and Rock Hurling (143) *et al.* that require ammunition.)

Obviously, the "winners" in the list above are the feats Spit Venom and Thunderclap, and, given the latter's prerequisites, the former's probably the only viable one. However, way too many creatures are immune to poison. (For example, creatures immune to poison include any creature that possesses the type construct, elemental, ooze, plant, or undead *plus* any outsider that possesses the subtype baatezu or tanar'ri.) At high levels, a PC will be lucky to fight a foe that's vulnerable to poison… then that PC must be even luckier to have that foe fail the initial Fortitude saving throw against the PC's poison. Good luck.

Were I asked, my recommendation for a multiclass character that's looking for a scaling ranged attack would be to have the character invest skill ranks—and possibly also feats—into the the skill Use Magic Device. The amount of gp a PC earns from adventuring scales by level so the magic items a PC buys do, too. Just buying a better ranged attack is *way* easier than trying to get feats to do what magic items should be doing for the PC.

Answer (score 4):

The only feat that does something somewhat similar to what you want is Magic Devotion, which gives you a ranged magic attack that scales with character level, but is usable only once a day for free, you need to expend turn/rebuke undead uses to use it more frequently than that.

Not a feat, but you could spend 100gp to undergo the Rite of Rebirth and become a Dragonborn of Bahamut, if you choose the Heart Draconic Aspect, you gain a breath weapon with damage that scales with your Hit Dice.

Generally speaking, abilities like what you describe would be too strong for a single feat, unless it has some very restrictive prerrequisites, that pretty much prohibits you from taking it unless you build your character around it, like Innate Spell.